# how to select the radio button in MVC view based on the model value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 web application I have hard coded radio button list in my view as below

```
<input type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="NotKnown" checked>
<input type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="CopyrightCategory1A">xxxxxxxx
<input type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="CopyrightCategory1B">yyyyyyyy
```

And I get value from the model as

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CopyrightCategory, new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Based on the value of m.CopyrightCategory I need to set the item as checked e.g. if the value of m.CopyrightCategory is "CopyrightCategory1B" then we will have it like this

```
<input type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="NotKnown">
<input type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="CopyrightCategory1A">xxxxxxxx
<input type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="CopyrightCategory1B" checked>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would use the `Html.RadioButton` helper method, but if you want to create the radio buttons manually, you can add an if-statement to determine if the radio button should be checked:

```
<input type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="CopyrightCategory1B" @if(m.CopyrightCategory == "CopyrightCategory1B"){<text>checked</text>}>
```

Comment: Looks like I am incorrect about requiring a value on the `checked` attribute: “The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.” http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700626/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-and-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-html5

Answer (score 1):

make something like this:

```
<input 
      type="radio" 
      name="CopyrightCategory" 
      value="CopyrightCategory1B" @(Model.CopyrightCategory == "CopyrightCategory1B" ? "checked" : string.Empty) >
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a short demo here is the link. I hope this will help you solve your problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/6tZgk/2/

HTML

```
<input id = 'check' type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="NotKnown" checked>
<input id='checkA' type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="CopyrightCategory1A">xxxxxxxx
<input id='checkB' type="radio" name="CopyrightCategory" value="CopyrightCategory1B">yyyyyyyy
 <span id="spanId">CopyrightCategory1B</span>
```

your @html.label will generate a  tag attach an id and will have the same functionality as the span i add here

jQuery

```
if($('#spanId').text() == 'CopyrightCategory1B') { $('#checkB').attr('checked','checked'); }
else if($('#spanId').text() == 'CopyrightCategory1A') {
$('#checkA').attr('checked', 'checked');;
```

}
else $('#check').attr('checked', 'checked');;

Comment: try to change the text from span and hit run to select another radio button