# How can I change a record in a database with a checkbox created with php

Tags: php, sql, checkbox

My check boxes are created using a while loop, so i can't put id's or names on everyone of them, so i can't change the record. The check boxes are ticked if a value is 1 and not ticked if a value is 0 in my table, that's good for checking, but cant I use them to change the value of record corresponding to the check box?
Here is my code:

```
<?php
                if($records === FALSE) { 
                    die(mysql_error());
                }

            while($student=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$student['SID']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$student['Student_Name']."</td>";
                if($student['Month_1'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox'  checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_2'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_3'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_4'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox'  checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_5'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox'  checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_6'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox'  checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_7'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_8'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_9'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_10'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_11'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                if($student['Month_12'] == 1){
                echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true'>"."</td>";
                }else{
                    echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: well, for one, NONE of your checkboxes have `name` attributes, so there's nothing to submit if/when that form gets submitted. they also have no `value` attribute, so even if they had a name, there'd be no data to submit along with the name, so there's no way to associate any particular checkbox with any of those high-repetivive `Month_X` bits you're testing.

Comment: maybe useful to you? [What is the proper way to check and uncheck a checkbox in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700626/what-is-the-proper-way-to-check-and-uncheck-a-checkbox-in-html5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider you should add a name to each checkbox containing month flag and student id like:

```
echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='true' name='Month_1[".$student['SID']."]'>"."</td>";
```

Then after your form is submitted you can change database values in arrays with a key matching $student['SID']:

```
while($student=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    $Month_1 = (!empty($_POST['Month_1'][$student['SID']])) ? 1 : 0; // returns 1 if checkbox was ticked or 0 if it wasn't
    // get the rest of months
    // update mysql record with `SID` = $student['SID']]
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in update_fees.php on line 28, do you have team viewer? it would be easier that way i guess... thanks for the help

Comment: What's the code on line 28? Unfortunately not able to use team viewer now

Comment: $q_m1="UPDATE bio_fees SET Month_1=$Month_1 WHERE SID=$student['SID']";

Comment: Try this: $q_m1="UPDATE bio_fees SET Month_1={$Month_1} WHERE SID=" . $student['SID'];

Answer (score 0):

First, no need to write this `echo "<td>"."<input type='checkbox' checked='false'>"."</td>";`, just write it like this `echo "<td><input type='checkbox' checked='false'></td>";` (no need for concatenation there)

Second, look this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

> This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Third, in order "*to change the value of record corresponding to the check box*"
you basically need to send data to some script on your server ( form -> changeDbEntry.php ) and that script should connect to DB and do the work you want.

I know this isn't the answer you expect, but solution without understanding of what is going on is next to useless. So...

Advice 1: read about html forms, POST/GET requests and AJAX (later read about headers, WebSockets, protocols...)

Advice 2: Check this out: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/